# how to automatically select entity reference field value from url when adding a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type "Students" which has an entity reference field "Course".

Course field shows a list of course nodes titles from a view.

When adding a new student node, I need the course field to be automatically selected as per the URL value.

I will pass the course ID in the URL like this.

```
/node/add/student/COURSEID
```

Any idea how to get this done ?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module

> Allow prepopulating any Entity reference field via URL

[README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/entityreference_prepopulate/tree/README.txt)

> **Usage**
>
> In order to pre-populate an entity reference field you have to supply
>   the parameter in the URL.
>
> The structure is node/add/article?[field_ref]=[id]
>
> Where [field_ref] is the name of the entity reference field and [id]
>   is the id of the entity being referenced.
>
> Examples:
>
> node/add/article?field_foo=1
>
> node/add/page?field_bar=1,2,3

Comment: this is something what I was looking for. But i already ended up doing it with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use hook_form_alter() and set a default value for the field. You can use arg() to get the course ID

Answer (score 0):

Another jQuery quick and dirty way.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    var the_url  = window.location.href;  
    var nid_from_url = the_url.substr(the_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    //change the selected value of the select list of courses.
    $('.page-node-add-offline-course-pictures #edit-field-offline-course-reference2-und').val(nid_from_url);
    });
```